# Foreign Key issue for creating a table using Java JDBC

Tags: java, sql, eclipse, ms-access, jdbc

The code works up to the `PRIMARY KEY` line in `CreateTableExample()`, but right below that, the `FOREIGN KEY` line keeps giving me an error, even when using different column names all around, as well as trying to add the table name to the `REFERENCES` line. Even though such are not necessary, the error still persists.

This is the error:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: unexpected token: (
```

Which does not help at all, because all of the parenthesis conform, making the line the error is on irrelevant, because it is on line 20, containing:  `stmt.executeUpdate(tablenm);`

I am using UcanAccess with Eclipse JDBC for MS Access

Full compiling program:

```
package test;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;
public class test2 {
    
    static void CreateTableExample(Connection connection, Scanner sc) {
 
        System.out.print("Enter table name: ");  
        String str = sc.nextLine(); 
        System.out.print("Enter column name: ");  
        String str2 = sc.nextLine();

          String tablenm ="CREATE TABLE `" + str + "` "
                 + "(`" + str2 + "` VARCHAR(255), "       
                +  "PRIMARY KEY(`" + str2 + "`), "
                 + " FOREIGN KEY (`" + str2 + "`) REFERENCES(`" + str2 + "`))";
          try {
          Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();

          stmt.executeUpdate(tablenm);
          }
          
          catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
          
}


        public static void main(String[] args) {
             
            String databaseLoc = "jdbc:ucanaccess://C:\\Users\\14129\\Desktop\\test.accdb";
             
            try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(databaseLoc)) {
                
                Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in); 
                CreateTableExample(connection, sc);
            }
                
            catch (SQLException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A foreign key typically references another column of another table (or the same table too), and you are missing that part. if you had the referenced table and column as a parameters, e.g. as `otherTable` and `otherColumn`, you could do:

```
      String tablenm ="CREATE TABLE `" + str + "` "
             + "(`" + str2 + "` VARCHAR(255), "       
             + "PRIMARY KEY(`" + str2 + "`), "
             + "FOREIGN KEY (`" + str2 + "`) " 
             + "REFERENCES `" + otherTable + "` (`" + otherColumn + "`))";
```

Comment: But otherTable isnt necessary, citing: https://www.w3resource.com/sql/creating-and-maintaining-tables/foreign-key.php

Comment: @sean That page includes the other table right there: `REFERENCES [primary_key_table] (column_list_of_primary_key_table) ...);`

Comment: I said I tried it with different table and column names in my original post and still have the same error.

Comment: Please include the `CREATE TABLE ...` of the other table.